# SSH Tunnelling through an IP alias

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxy

I have a machine with 3 IPv4. Let's call them as example:

8.8.8.1 (eth0) (main ip) 
8.8.8.2 (eth0:1) (ip alias)
8.8.8.3 (eth0:2) (ip alias)

if I create an SSH tunnel and configure my browser to use that tunnel as a socks proxy, all outgoing requests seem to be going through main IP only. So if I create a tunnel through an IP alias and set it as proxy in Firefox, then check what IP is showing up, always shows main IP.

Is there a way I can set the outgoing connections to show as the IP aliases that I'm proxying through?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your default route is on the eth0 held network.
Your proxied traffic isn't directly linked to your IP alias (the traffic is generated locally throught sshd process which will manage the return path to your machine). So the outcoming/proxied traffic will basically obey the standard mechanism : using default route on default interface to reach the destination.

You have to specifically tag packets based on some criteria to route them throught an other IP.
This is a complex topic, i suggest you took a look at this website which is the official generalist documentation for this topic: https://lartc.org/

You can also push your SSH server in a LXC container that would hold the 8.8.8.2 address  (using for example a bridged setup to give LXC access to your network). Since LXC process are isolated from main host, and can only use the ressource you provided it, then all its traffic will go throught 8.8.8.2...

Oh, also, note that this is not a good idea to use valid and routed IP address for your examples and/or private network: 8.8.8.0/25 is a valid internet subnet owned by Google. Don't overlap it or you may lost access to some of Google stuff.

Use 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x instead.